# Dynamic method execution by name in Spring framework

Tags: spring

There are several injected Services, and there is one Rest service. Rest service accespts Service name and method name as string, and then method should be called.
Is there any solutions?

REST (methodName:String) -> lookup method by name and then invoke it

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No, i'm stuck in googling possible solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of reflection here.

Use the string service name  to fetch the bean instance from spring context. Using this bean instance locate the method to be executed. See below for sample code and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) for reference.

```
    Object t = appContext.getBean("nameOfService"); // fetch the bean instance
    Class<?> c = appContext.getType("nameOfService"); // determine type i.e. Class

    Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : allMethods) {
        String mname = m.getName();
        if (!mname.startsWith("nameOfMethod")) {
            continue;
        }
        try {
            m.setAccessible(true);
            Object o = m.invoke(t, args[1], args[2], args[3]);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException x) {
            Throwable cause = x.getCause();
            err.format("invocation of %s failed: %s%n",
               mname, cause.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**P.S.:** I haven't tried it but this should work. Let know in comments in case of any issue(s).

Comment: indeed it is .. but given the scenario it has to be done.